# Links ignored in quick documentation popup

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, intellij-idea

I included a link to a website in my documentation. When I open the quick documentation popup the link is just displayed as regular text instead of a link. So it's not highlighted and clicking on the link doesn't do anything.

According to [Effective Dart: Documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation#markdown) I should be able to use Markdown formatting but it just doesn't work as you can see:

[image]

Am I missing something? Is this by design? Are links supposed to be ignored?

I'm using Android Studio 4.1.3 on macOS Big Sur 11.2.3.

Comment: It looks unsupported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38160

Answer (score 0):

The `*` create a list. I think in the documentation they added `*` to list the differents possibilities to add a link...

Try : `[ref link]: https://google.com` or simply `https://google.com`

Comment: It shouldn't matter that * creates a list. If simply just entering the URL would work, I would've have a link in a list but I have regular text in a list. I also tried all variants of link formattings including both of yours but they still are displayed as regular text. Did you try it? Does it work in your IDE?